# RS-232 erratic behavior - Follow up

Tags: c#, serial-port

Please excuse my ignorance… What I'm doing must be really simple but, it's not working 'logically'. As you know, I am dealing with a 'serial' device. I tried all I could with VisualBasic but it's not working for me, so I'm working in c#. I'm stumbling on the following piece of code:

```
            string[] RawData = new string[205];

            _serialPort.Write("D5\r\n");
```

First try: Hardcoded it 201 times.

```
            RawData[0] = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            RawData[1] = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            RawData[2] = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            RawData[3] = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            RawData[4] = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            RawData[5] = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            RawData[6] = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            RawData[7] = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            RawData[8] = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            RawData[9] = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            //....x 201 times
            RawData[201] = _serialPort.ReadLine();
```

Second try:

```
            for (int i = 0; i <= 202; i++)
            {
                RawData[i] = _serialPort.ReadLine();
                // Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
```

As you can, I need to create an array to hold the 'spectral data' returned by the device.

My initial reaction was to use a loop to fetch the data from the serial port. Easy enough, except that execution "vanishes" during the loop and the program hangs.

I tried adding a Sleep of 500ms between each ReadLine to no avail. If I manually loop through each ReadLines, in debugging mode, it works.

But if I set a breakpoint on the next instruction, that's outside the loop, then all bets are off.

So, it maybe awkward or amateurish but if I issue 201 individual ReadLine statements, as shown above (I'm only showing 9), then it works?

Comment: It may not be clear above but either I manually step 201  ReadLine() statements OR I go through the loop 201 times -- my code does not do both. The way I am showing above is for illustrative purpose (in case someone asks).

Comment: Out of your 11 questions, you have 5 with answers but none of them accepted. Please consider accepting and upvoting good answers.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "all bets are off"? Is your process stuck on reading or any exception thrown?

Answer (score 2):

This `for` cycle:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 202; i++)
```

issues 203 reads: for indexes from 0 to 202. If your device provides only 201 lines of results, then when reading the 202nd line your code never receives it will wait for the device 'forever'.

Comment: You were on the right track, Ondrej!!!

Answer (score 0):

As @Ondrej Tucny says, you might be making more call and `SerialPort` is waiting for it, so you can't pass to next instruction.

If this is the problem, I'll suggest don't use `ReadLine`.

`ReadLine` is not good because it will "wait" until it receives EOL, and the timeout is set in serial port.

If you don't know how many data you would get, `ReadLine` is a bad idea. Everytime you called it, you might need to hang until it timeout or luckily pass when you receive EOL.

I'll suggest you use [`Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.read?view=netframework-4.8) or [`ReadExisting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting?view=netframework-4.8)

Another workaround is set your [`SerialPort.ReadTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readtimeout?view=netframework-4.8) smaller enough and catch `TimeoutException`, so process won't hang on waiting.

Comment: I experimented with Read, and that's actually the instruction I'm using to fetch the "other kinds of data" from the device but Read did not work (for some reason) on this group of data. I tried "ReadExisting" at some point but that did not work. Thanks for pitching in, Louis :-)

Comment: Then set lower ReadTimeout is better in your case. If you don't want to handle dirty works.

Answer (score -2):

I hate to say… (Don't mind if I look a fool…) The reason control was never coming back to me is that by looping 201 times, unknowingly, I was trying to retrieve data that "did not exist" from the device -- egg on my face. I had to go through my 201 manual ReadLine statements… To find out that, at some point, I also lost control? I started to insert breakpoints 50, 100, 150 and then 200 to notice that there was a point beyond which, the program would stop responding. By looking at the captured data, it started to make sense (I could see the 'logic' -- ha! ha! ha!). So, I deleted my 201 repetitive, ugly statements and just changed the loop max value to 176 and everything was hunky-dorey. Thanks for your patience.